# Why shows a error message if I add two text box using PHP?

Tags: php

I am learning some PHP Stuffs. I am trying to add two number from a text box but it shows a error message. This error actually came from following `<?php echo $c;?>` line but it look like ok for me. I used "empty " tag `<?php echo empty($c);?>` to hide error but it didn't  work. Why?

```
            <body>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
                {
                    $a=$_POST['no1'];
                    $b=$_POST['no2'];
                    $c=$a+$b;

                }
            ?>


                            <form method="post">
                            <table border="3">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Number 1</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="no1"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Number 2</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="no2"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Result</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $c;?>" /></td>
                                    </tr> 
                                    <tr align="center">
                                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit_btn"/></td>
                                    </tr>                
                            </table>
                            </form>

            </body>
```

Here is my error message 
[image]

Comment: because what if the IF Statement evals to FALSE, then $c will not exist and you cannot echo a non-existent variable.

Comment: Initialize it with `$c = null;` before the `if()` block.

Comment: Is that an actual php page (extension ends in .php), running on a server with PHP enabled?

Comment: Could you please explain a little more. I couldn't catch your answer.I declared $c here "$c=$a+$b;" . I am working on a local host using Wamp .Thanks

Comment: Yeah but what if the submit_btn isn't set, then those three lines of code never get run.

Comment: @KevinJohn You only initialize it if the `$_POST['submit_btn']` is set. Therefore, the first time the page loads it is _not_ set because the form has not been submitted and `$c` doesn't get a value. Initialize it to null before the `if()`.

Comment: You can use `echo @$a;` to hide any errors if you so wish, highly not recommended.

Comment: please @t3chguy then don't give them this option. -j08691 i love if someone wants to help but your question was special.

Comment: He asked for a way to 'hide' the errors. Do not tell me to not try and help him with what he wants, even if its not a very common practice in PHP.

Comment: if he wants to ``error_reporting(0);``

Comment: That's even worse than hiding the errors only on one line.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski ,(about Duplicate question issue) I read all the answer but it answers not meet my question.

Comment: every option to hide a error is equal worse, you don't do it

Comment: @KevinJohn there are three people giving you an almost identical answer, mathematics itself states the chances of us being correct are higher than that of yourself, so how about you believe us; that $_POST['submit_btn'] is undefined until that button is pressed.

Comment: Actually, even go ahead and try it: `<?php phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES); ?>` at the top of your php file.

Comment: @KevinJohn You need to understand that upon first arriving at the page, before submitting the form, `$_POST['submit_btn']` has no value. That's when you see the error. If you proceed to submit the form, it will have a value and `$c` gets defined. The solution is simple - initialize it ahead of time.  `$c = null; if (isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) {...// etc...}`

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski , @t3chguy  , I initialised the $c= null. Now its working well. Thanks for the answer everybody.   Now my code is                 <?php
     $c="";
                    if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
                    {
                        $a=$_POST['no1'];
                        $b=$_POST['no2'];
      $c=$a+$b;
                        
                    }
                ?>

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski , Need to change the title for some other  for future reference that you mentioned as it is duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because if $_POST['submit_btn'] is not set your $c variable doesn't exist, yet you are using it in the form

Comment: But I set it here "<input type="submit" name="submit_btn"/>"

Comment: @KevinJohn that's only once its pressed, until then there is no POST data in the page.